# Get string by regex bash script

Tags: bash

I work with bash script. I have lines

```
3    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:22
4    ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state NEW tcp dpt:80
```

I want to get "22,80" from this lines.Can anybodey help me?

Comment: You can check here http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_02.html#sect_04_02_02 or you can do it easily in perl, python etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the delimiter before 20 and 80 is `:`, you can mainly do it with `cut`:

```
$ cut -d: -f2 file
22
80
```

With `bash`:

```
$ while read line
do
  echo ${line#*:}
done < file
22
80
```

Even with `awk`:

```
$ awk -F: '{print $2}' file
22
80
```

And to complete it, with `sed`:

```
$ sed  's/.*://' file
22
80
```

Comment: `perl -F: -lane 'print $F[1]' file` ... +1 ;)

Comment: Jaypal and his new look to the rescue :) Thanks for improving my answer!

Comment: @fedorqui @jaypal : dang `perl` is so verbose compared to `awk -F: '$_=$2'`

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=":"} {print $2}' file
```